# Pass Parameter to a redirected script in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, command

I have two scripts, suppose they are s1.sh and s2.sh.

In s1, the code is

```
step = 0
.
.(omitted)
.
if [ $step -eq 19 ]; then

    ./s2.sh
```

In s2, the code is

```
step=0
.
. (many codes here, but omitted)
.
if [ $step -eq 18 ]; then
  print "hello"
```

I want to run s1 from step 19, and then as s1 would call s2, I hope s2 could directly go to step 19 as well.

I heard someone talking about this before but I really could not remember the exact method. I am thinking the command codes to do this would be like :

```
./s1.sh --step 19 [some code?]--step 18
```

Any idea how to write the command line that could pass argument to two scripts as above ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `step` to be the same in both, run `export step` in s1. Once you do that, the `step` variable will just be present in s2 without having to be explicitly passed when you call it.

If you want to set a different `step` in s2 than in s1, prepend `step=whatever` to the call to s2. For example, to make it be 8 in s2, you'd do this: `step=8 ./s2.sh`.

Comment: I think export could work only two parameters are the same ? what if they are different ?

Comment: @exteralvictor Are you asking how to make `step` in s2 have a different value than it does in `s1`?

Comment: Yes, to be more specific, I want to use a command line to do that. So when redirected to s2, the step parameter in s2 would be 9 instead of 0.

Comment: @exteralvictor Okay, answer edited.

Comment: can it be done in command line without changing the original s1 or s2 ?

Comment: @exteralvictor If both variables have the same name, but they need to have different values, and s1 calls s2, then no, there's no way to do that from the command line without editing at least one of them.

Answer (score 0):

One method of achieving this result is to use positional arguments:

This is the test1.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

step=$1
step2=$2

if [[ step -eq 19 ]]; then
    ./test2.sh $step2
fi
```

and the test2.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

step=$1

if [[ step -eq 18 ]]; then
    echo "success - step 18 executed"
fi
```

Then you can call test1.sh (in your case s1.sh) like so:

```
./test1.sh 19 18
```

After which you should get the success message. Although this does involve editing the original scripts a little, it does offer a great deal of flexibility and makes extending both scripts more straightforward. If you do decide to use this method, I would strongly advise establishing default values for the step and step2 vars.